# RcppArmadillo "ReferenceInputParameter is not a template"

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to build a user package that has been building fine on my colleague's windows box which has R 2.15.1 installed.  My config is:

R 2.15.3, RTools 3.0, Rcpp 0.10.4, RcppArmadillo 0.3.920.1, RStudio 0.97.551

This is the first compilation instance when I run "R CMD INSTALL mypackage".  indfunForecast.cpp is one of the source files within the package.

```
>g++ -m32 -I"D:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
-I"D:/R/win-library/2.15/Rcpp/include" -I"D:/R/win-library/2.15/RcppArmadillo/include" 
-I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include" 
-O2 -Wall -mtune=core2 
-c indfunForecast.cpp -o indfunForecast.o
```

The error messages that follow are:

```
In file included from D:/R/win-library/2.15/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:30:0,
             from indfunForecast.cpp:16:
D:/R/win-library/2.15/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:99:33: 
error: 'ConstReferenceInputParameter' is not a template
D:/R/win-library/2.15/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:100:33: 
error: 'ReferenceInputParameter' is not a template
D:/R/win-library/2.15/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:101:33: 
error: 'ConstInputParameter' is not a template
```

Any idea what's going on???

Appreciate your help.
Sachko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the newest RcppArmadillo which needs the newest Rcpp, which you don't have (and I won't bore you with the details, but it is CRAN-related).

Install Rcpp 0.10.5 from source, and things should work.

Comment: I also wondered if userX needed to update R to match RTools as well.

Comment: perhaps the R level protection in DESCRIPTION is not enough and we should have code that asserts that Rcpp's version is high enough in the headers of RcppArmadillo.

Comment: DESCRIPTION is usually enough -- here I didn't update it as I uploaded both packages jointly in a tied submission ensuring they both would get onto CRAN. But it was only this week that I learned about the old-R-release issue with Rcpp holding it back on Windows-only. So in that sense clearly my mistake for not requiring the correct Rcpp in RcppArmadillo's DESCRIPTION, but it "only" affects Windows per Uwe's choice to not build if the previous R release fails.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated to the latest R and Rcpp, and the problem cleared.

Comment: Great, and sorry you needed the manual step this time. Usually the two fit on all platforms.