# how to match versions of Rcpp and RcppArmadillo for older R on windows?

Tags: r, rcpp

I created RcppArmadillo package on windows (Win 7, 64 bit) using R 3.1.2 and the latest versions of Rcpp 0.11.3 and RcppArmadillo 0.4.600.0. Package compiles, installs, and runs fine. Afterwards i wrote some code to use BigMatrix from bigmemory package with my RcppArmadillo package. As it turns out bigmemory is not available for R 3.1.2 on windows. To use bigmemory i downgraded R to R 2.15.3 and got Rcpp 0.10.4 and RcppArmadillo 0.4.000.2 for it from CRAN. Now i can use bigmemory but i cannot get my RcppArmadillo package to compile. Basically, it barfs a long list of error messages starting with

```
C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:99:33: error: 'ConstReferenceInputParameter' is not a template
```

The errors look like a version incompatibility issue [RcppArmadillo "ReferenceInputParameter is not a template"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369604/rcpparmadillo-referenceinputparameter-is-not-a-template) for which Dirk recommended installing Rcpp 0.10.5 from source. So i found tarball of Rcpp 0.10.5 and installed it manually. Problem is that i still get a ton of different error messages

```
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpparma_hello_world.cpp -o rcpparma_hello_world.o
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rcppArma.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o rcpparma_hello_world.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/bin/i386 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/bin/i386 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/bin/i386 -lR
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `Rcpp::internal::enterRNGScope()'
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `SEXPREC*    Rcpp::internal::r_true_cast<14>(SEXPREC*)'
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `Rcpp::RObject::RObject(SEXPREC*)'
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type* Rcpp::internal::r_vector_start<14>(SEXPREC*)'
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type* Rcpp::internal::r_vector_start<14>(SEXPREC*)'
```

I suspect it is still version incompatibility issue, but i have no idea how to match Rcpp version and RcppArmadillo version. Is there a compatibility table, could someone give a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

*All* CRAN packages have an `Archive/` subdirectory.  By picking the date of the last available `bigmemory` package you can find that corresponding package for `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`: the most recent release *prior to that particular `bigmemory` release*.  You can then download and install these (provided you are set up to install from source, which I presume you are, given the context).

There is some ongoing work by some folks giving 'snap-shotting' ability but I am not aware of a high-level helper function you could use right now.

*Edit:* What you should probably do here, though, is to take a recent `bigmemory` *source* package and install from source.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, this is precisely what i was looking for. For my bigmemory 4.2.11 last packages prior to release are Rcpp 0.9.5 and RcppArmadillo 0.2.27. Rcpp installed fine, there is a weird error with RcppArmadillo that i don't know how to hack as there is no makefile. The error is: g++.exe: error: C:/Program: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/Rcpp/lib/i386/libRcpp.a: No such file or directory.  Basically compilation line breaks in the middle after "C:/Program" for some unclear reason.

Comment: The general recommendation is not to install R in a directory with spaces: `C:/Program` is probably a truncated part of `C:/Program Files`.  I always use `C:/opt/R`; newer versions are better protected against this but with something as old as Rcpp 0.9.5 you may be out of alternatives. But also see my edit:  maybe you can install a newer bigmemory from source.

Comment: The first bigmemory that installed with R.3.1.2 was 4.2.11.The latest versions before were Rcpp 0.9.5 and RcppArmadillo 0.2.27. However, i am not able to compile my package now. When i try sourceCpp i get error "'sourceCpp' is not an exported object from 'namespace:Rcpp'". If i try to install the package with CMD INSTALL i get a bunch of errors from RcppExports.cpp, which i thought was internally generated. First errors were: "RcppExports.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* rcppArma_rcpparma_outerproduct(SEXP)':
RcppExports.cpp:30:9: error: 'input_parameter' is not a member of 'Rcpp::traits'"

Comment: You appear to have more general problems getting Rcpp to work.  There are many documents and tutorials suggesting how to compile packages for R on Windows, and how to build Rcpp from source on Windows,  Those may help.  I have nothing more to add to this and will recuse myself from this thread.   If you need more help, consider the rcpp-devel mailing list.

Comment: OK :). I am far from expert on building in general or on Rcpp. Still, i installed a ton of packages for R from source and  Rcpp and RcppArmadillo included. Last versions work fine. In general, installing from source usually works or requires minor hacks. Getting these old versions of Rcpp and RcppArmadillo to work together seem to require more than that. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Actually, Dirk. Only reason i bother you is to say you were completely right :). Some old version of bigmemory did install fine in R-3.1.2. So, i am good to go. Bunch of old bigmemory are Unix only or 32 bit only, but that's a different story. Also, some of the problems with old versions of RcppArmadillo seemed to do with me using new armadillo library API, which i use in pure c++, independently of R. It'd be great if RcppArmadillo allowed to link to armadillo, instead of imbedding some version of it. But maybe i am wrong in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Phew, glad to hear you got it sorted out. But no, we don't want external Armadillo with linking -- the header-only mode is much better.  And please do feel free to accept the answer and its comment tail.

Answer (score 1):

The [checkpoint](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html) package can create a local R library that contains packages as of a given date.

There is a tutorial [[here]](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/10/introducing-rrt.html).

Comment: Subject to the constraint that _Snapshot archives exist starting from 2014-09-17_.

Comment: In other words, this is true in general but not an answer to the question asked here.

Comment: R 2.15.3, as stated in the OPs question, gives a pretty good idea.

Comment: Many things _might be_ something or other.  The point is that you suggested checkpoint, which does not get anywhere near the period he chose to pick versions from.  So checkpoint is still an inapplicable answer here.

Comment: Maybe checkpoint's start date is too recent but on the other hand maybe its not.and in that case this provides a particularly easy solution so its worth a try.